# Does returning home (after a residence permit in Netherlands is revoked) with IOM get you an entry ban?

Tags: schengen, removal, schengen-visas

A letter from IND (Immigration and Naturalization Service) has asked that I, together with family, depart Netherlands within 24 hours. We are about to return home using IOM (International Organization for Migration) free ticket and etc.

Does returning home with IOM free tickets automatically impose entry ban on us? Has anyone travelled/return home from Schengen with IOM?

IOM is International Organisation for Migration.

Comment: On paper, no. They are two separate organisations and IOM has no sovereignty to impose bans.  Realistically, you can count on not returning for a while even in the absence of a formal ban.

Comment: Whatever causes the Dutch authorities to issue a get-out-of-here-right-now order on day's notice in the first place is probably quite enough to make future travel difficult, no matter which kind of travel arrangement you used.

Comment: David, IOM is International Organisation for Migration, which helps people to return and integrate to their home country

Comment: @pnuts Not necessarily, an injunction to leave the territory is not a ban, especially one with a delay for voluntary departure (even if 24 hours seems very short, it means detention was not deemed necessary). [In fact Dutch law specifies that a ban can only be imposed *after* that delay elapsed](https://www.rijksoverheid.nl/onderwerpen/terugkeer-vreemdelingen/inhoud/terugkeerbeleid) and when the authorities have reasons to impose a ban right away, they do not give any delay.

Answer (score 3):

Summarizing the feedback given in comments, 
**no there is no formal entry ban imposed on you**, apparently [a Dutch law](https://www.rijksoverheid.nl/onderwerpen/terugkeer-vreemdelingen/inhoud/terugkeerbeleid) even specifies that a ban can only be imposed after that delay elapsed ([toh to Relaxed](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/76028/does-returning-home-after-a-residence-permit-in-netherlands-is-revoked-with-io#comment184909_76028)).

However something caused the Dutch authorities to order your fairly immediate departure so **going back is unrealistic in the near future, even if there is no formal ban.**